# Python display "Memory Address not Object List"?

Tags: python, list, object, memory-address

I am trying to output conflict between class of class scheduling problem using hill climbing algorithm, but it keep showing memory address in the second column when method "conflict.getConflictBetweenClasses()" is call.
Here my code where I print "table of conflicts":

```
 def display_conflicts(self, schedule):       
       table_conflicts = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Conflict Type', 'Conflict Between Classes'])
       for conflict in schedule.getConflicts():
          table_conflicts.align['Conflict Type'] = "l"  
          table_conflicts.add_row([conflict.getConflictType(), conflict.getConflictBetweenClasses()])
        #  table_conflicts.align = 'l'
       print(table_conflicts)
       return self
```

Here is my Conflict Class:

```
class Conflict:
    class ConflictType(Enum):
        numbOfStudents__ = 1
        InstructorBooking = 2
        RoomBooking = 3

    def __init__(self, conflictType, conflictBetweenClasses):
        self.conflictType = conflictType
        self.conflictBetweenClasses = conflictBetweenClasses

    def getConflictType(self): return self.conflictType.name.split(".")[-1]
    def getConflictBetweenClasses(self): return self.conflictBetweenClasses


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.conflictType) + " " + str(self.conflictBetweenClasses)
```

Here is my Schedule Class:

```
class Schedule:
    classNumb = 0

    def __init__(self, schedule):
        self.conflicts = []
        self.data = schedule
        self.classes = [] * data.getNumberOfClasses()
      #  self.classes = list(self.getClasses())  # Create a copy of the list
        self.classes.extend(self.getClasses())
        self.findAllConflicts()

    def initialize(self):
        for dept in data.getDepts():
            for course in dept.getCourses():
                newClass = Class(self.classNumb, dept, course)
                newClass.setMeetingTime(data.getMeetingTimes()[int(len(data.getMeetingTimes()) * random())])
                newClass.setRoom(data.getRooms()[int(len(data.getRooms()) * random())])
                newClass.setInstructor(course.getInstructors()[int(len(course.getInstructors()) * random())])
                self.classes.append(newClass)
                self.classNumb += 1
        return self

    def findAllConflicts(self):
        conflicts=[]
        for i in self.getClasses():
            if i.getRoom().getSeatingCapacity() < i.getCourse().getMaxNumbOfStudents():
                conflictBetweenClasses = []
                conflictBetweenClasses.append(i)
                conflict = Conflict(Conflict.ConflictType.numbOfStudents__, conflictBetweenClasses)
                self.conflicts.append(conflict)
            for y in self.classes[self.classes.index(i):]:
                if i.getMeetingTime() == y.getMeetingTime() and i.getId() != y.getId():
                    if i.getRoom() == y.getRoom():
                        conflictBetweenClasses = []
                        conflictBetweenClasses.append(i)
                        conflictBetweenClasses.append(y)
                        conflict = Conflict(Conflict.ConflictType.RoomBooking, conflictBetweenClasses)
                        self.conflicts.append(conflict)
                    if i.getInstructor() == y.getInstructor():
                        conflictBetweenClasses=[]
                        conflictBetweenClasses.append(i)
                        conflictBetweenClasses.append(y)
                        conflict = Conflict(Conflict.ConflictType.InstructorBooking, conflictBetweenClasses)
                        self.conflicts.append(conflict)
        return self

    def getClasses(self): return self.classes

    def getData(self): return self.data

    def getConflicts(self): return self.conflicts
  
    def toString(self):
        schedule_list = []
        for cls in self.classes:
            class_info = f"{cls.getDept().getName()}, {cls.getCourse().getNumber()}, {cls.getRoom().getNumber()}, {cls.getInstructor().getId()}, {cls.getMeetingTime().getId()}"
            schedule_list.append(class_info)
        return schedule_list
```

I tried many time to modify **str()** in class Conflict, but still outputting the same result. Any help will be really appreciated.